# Update one parameter when other is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple task manager, and besides `completed:boolean` column I have a `completed_time:datetime` column, which I need to store time, when user mark task as completed.

There is a solution with `hidden_field` and filling it with current time by JS, when user check task, as completed, but I think this is not a good idea, and it must be done on controller or model level.

So, now I have this in my `Task` model:

```
before_update :add_completed_time
.
.
.
def add_completed_time
  if self.completed?
    self.completed_time = DateTime.now
  end
end
```

But it updates `completed_time` column each time, when task is updated after completion (for ex., when I mark it as `archived`).

How can I call this method ONLY, when task was marked as completed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add one more condition that will check if `completed_time` already has a value. If yes, don't update it.

```
def add_completed_time
  if self.completed? and self.completed_time == nil
    self.completed_time = DateTime.now
  end
end
```